# d3 sunburst - highlight the whole path while hovering any of its child/parent nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I'm looking to highlight the whole path of a sunburst chart, no matter which child/parent node that I am on.

I have seen the sunburst sequence chart, and I want to do pretty much the same thing but I want the whole path to be highlighted despite which parent/child node I am hovering.

I believe it has something to do with the getAncestor() function and the unshift, but I am having trouble figuring out how to get my desired result.

https://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/766f8f6d31f645c39f488a0befa1e3c8

Comment: So if you hover an element, you want to highlight the ancestors (as in the example), plus *all* of the element's children?

Comment: Each ancestor of the ancestor in the path.. if that make senses. Like.. if you hover over a node in the outermost ring, it highlights the path until the center. I want that whole path to be lit up, despite which node I'm on in that given path.